# Ошибка: Failed to open X11 display

Tags: linux, sfml, imgui

Я пытаюсь установить программу тестирования (https://github.com/o-reo/push_swap_visualizer) на мой Microsoft Visual Code, работающий на wsl-ubuntu. Для этой программы-тестера требуются C++17, cmake, SFML и ImGui.
Я установил все кроме ImGui. Я не понял как его правильно установить в данный проект.
Когда я запускаю "cmake...", я получаю такое сообщение об ошибке:
`Failed to open X11 display; make sure the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly`
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: cmake хочет запустить какую-то gui-программу, но эта программа не видит x11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно установить в Windows X-сервер. Много где советуют, и я сам пользуюсь [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/)

По историческим причинам у меня установлена WSL первой версии. Поэтому мне достаточно в терминале задать две переменные окружения:

```
$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
$ export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

и вуа-ля -- графическое приложение `xterm` отрисовывается в Windows.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дабы узнать, какая у вас версия WSL, наберите в терминале команду

```
PS C:\> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Running         1
```

У вас, скорее всего, установлена вторая версия. WSL2 устроена как настоящая виртуальная машина с отдельной сетью, поэтому там нужно настраивать хитрее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61110604/9047589

В любом случае вам нужно установить в терминале, где вы собираете приложение, переменную `DISPLAY`. Именно так графические приложения узнают о том, где находится графический сервер, отрисовывающий для них окошки и вообще всю графику.